# Checking for optimal path

Tags: c#, algorithm, path

I'm trying to find out if the algorithm i wrote returns the most optimal path for visiting every node in a graph. I'm trying to traverse the graph like you would mow a lawn or clean your house with a vacuum cleaner, or plow a field. I get a path back but is there a way to check if its the most optimal. Is there an API or online service that i could use to check it?

Ive looked at Dijkstra and A* algorithms as well as BFS and DFS but I'm not sure how to validate the path i get is the most efficient.

Given a graph how do i find the quickest and most efficient path that visits all the nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this in an NP Hard problem known as the travelling salesman problem.

There is therefore no known polynomial time solution. To traverse the entire solution space would take !N iterations (where N is the number of nodes). However, there are several solutions which can give you GOOD solutions, if not the best.

I would look into Simulated Annealing as a method to get a short path between all nodes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

Comment: Simulated annealing is a *lot* of fun.

Comment: What if i wanted to do something like finding the most optimal path for a vacuum cleaner going through a house or mowing a lawn?

Comment: The annealing method seems best for metallurgy and finding the highest point in a mountain range, but doesnt seem as well suited to going form point A to B visiting all nodes

Comment: basically, you're looking at a combinatorial optimization problem. In which there are a huge number of possible permutations but most of them are crap. If you imagine the fitness of a certain permutation the 'height' of a certain point in the mountain range, you are then aiming to find the 'highest' point in the solution space, because that is the fittest solution.